# Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence of positives st $\exists n_0$ st $0<\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\leq c<1,\ \forall n\geq n_0$. Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I can show that this sequence converges because it is monotonic and bounded, but I'm having trouble showing that the limit is 0.

My attempt:

Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = L$, thus $$\forall\epsilon>0\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\geq n_0 \ (|x_n - L|<\epsilon)$$
For each natural $k$, let $\epsilon=\frac{c}{k}$, hence there exist $n_{0,k}$ s.t. $\forall n>n_{0,k}$

$$L-\frac{c}{k} < x_n < L+\frac{c}{k}$$
and
$$L-\frac{c}{k} < x_{n+1} < L+\frac{c}{k}$$

but $$0<x_{n+1} < cx_n<x_n$$
so
$$L-\frac{c}{k} < cx_n < L+\frac{c}{k}$$
$$\frac{L}{c}-\frac{1}{k} < x_n < \frac{L}{c}+\frac{1}{k}\implies |x_n-\frac{L}{c}|<\frac{1}{k} ,\ \forall n\geq n_{0,k}$$

I thought of using this to somehow show that $L$ cannot be greater than 0 by making $k$ large enough, but don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

For $n>n_0$ we have,

$$x_{n}\le cx_{n-1} \to x_n\le c^2x_{n-2}\to ...\to x_n\le c^{n-n_0}x_{n_0}$$
so,
$$0<x_n\le c^{n-n_0}x_{n_0}$$

What about using Squeeze theorem?

Or, if you want to use the definition of limit, choose $n$ s.t., $c^{n-n_0}x_{n_0}<\epsilon.$

Comment: The inequality $x_{n + 1}  \le cx_n$ holds only if $n\geq n_0$. You have to slightly modify your answer.

Comment: @Gary, you are right, sorry.

Comment: @Gary Or wlog $n_0 = 0$ since convergence is not affected by finitely many terms of the sequence.

Comment: @MathQED Yes, but then it would be cleaner to re-define $x_n$ or state this explicitly.

Comment: @Arnaldo Great! Thanks. I couldn't use the squeeze theorem because it was left as an exercise to prove it latter in the problem set, but your second suggestion works just fine. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy approach. You already know that $x_n$ converges and being positive the limit $L$ must be non-negative. Suppose that $L>0$ then $x_{n+1}/x_n\to L/L=1$. But this contradicts $x_{n+1}/x_n\leq c<1$. Hence we have $L=0$.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to showing that
$c^n \to 0$.
To do this, let
$c=1/(1+b)$
where $b > 0$.

Then, by Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+b)^n \ge 1+nb
\ge nb
=n(1/c-1)
= nc/(1-c)
$

so
$c^n < (1-c)/(nc)$.